# What's wrong with my Like Query JDBC(Derby)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, derby

Until now, I'm confused when to double quote and single quote queries.
My Search query doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to use % and surround the component Search_Textfield with % to get results but i think there's something wrong with my query.
Here's my code.

```
private void Search_searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    try{
        String myUrl="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/EMPLOYEEINFO";
        String username="ADMIN1";
        String password="ADMIN1";
        Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, username, password);
        Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();

        String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID LIKE '%' '"+Search_TxtField.getText()+"' '%' ";

        ResultSet myRs = myStatement.executeQuery(myQuery);
        DefaultListModel myDLM = new DefaultListModel();

        while(myRs.next()){
          myDLM.addElement(myRs.getString(1));
        }//end of while loop

        Search_List.setModel(myDLM);


    }//end of try
    catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
    }//end of catch
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your single quotes.
Instead of using

```
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID LIKE '%' '"+Search_TxtField.getText()+"' '%' ";
```

Try using:

```
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID LIKE '% "+Search_TxtField.getText()+" %' ";
```

The single quotes must include the `%`, so you search like `'%testString%'`

Answer (score 0):

Did You try declare myQuery like:

```
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID LIKE '%"+Search_TxtField.getText()+"%' ";
```

or instead of like just equal '='

```
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='"+Search_TxtField.getText()'";
```